# for loop repeat when condtion is true

Tags: javascript

I have json value.

Here is my JSON.

```
"notifications" : {
    "0" : {
      "FROM" : 1,
      "MSG" : "Admin Saravanan has sent new circular (Message from admin) ",
      "RECEIVE_TIME" : "2017-03-18 06:17:26",
      "SEND_TIME" : "2017-03-17 02:38:01",
      "STATUS" : "ON",
      "TO" : "ALL",
      "TYPE" : "EVENT"
    },
    "1" : {
      "FROM" : 1,
      "MSG" : "New visitor muruganantham.k.m checkin your flat.",
      "RECEIVE_TIME" : "2017-03-23 06:33:06",
      "SEND_TIME" : "2017-03-23 11:45:26 am",
      "STATUS" : "ON",
      "TO" : "2",
      "TYPE" : "VISITORS"
    }
```

and this json assigned to arr value.

Here is my function

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i].STATUS === 'ON')
            {
                this.play();
            }   
        }

        this.play()
        {
            //arr[0].STATUS changed to OFF
            //Here Updated the value 
            //the status value changed to OFF.
        }
```

I need the for loop first arr[0] value changed status OFF.after will alow the arr[1] value.

How can i do this .

Kinldy advice me,

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. Do you want to loop over the `notifications` and work with each object?

Comment: Thanks.I said arr[0] value Changed .It's mean array of first value now ON.and update OFF.after arr[1] value entered the forloop

Comment: Can u help me.Yes i want Loop over the notifications each Object

Answer (score 0):

You can't treat JSON as an array.
If I understand what you are trying to do (and I'm not entirely sure), it should be like this:
Use Object.keys(notifications) to get the keys of the JSON object, than you can switch the statuses.

```
var notifications = {
    "0" : {
        "FROM" : 1,
        "MSG" : "Admin Saravanan has sent new circular (Message from admin) ",
        "RECEIVE_TIME" : "2017-03-18 06:17:26",
        "SEND_TIME" : "2017-03-17 02:38:01",
        "STATUS" : "ON",
        "TO" : "ALL",
        "TYPE" : "EVENT"
    },
    "1" : {
        "FROM" : 1,
        "MSG" : "New visitor muruganantham.k.m checkin your flat.",
        "RECEIVE_TIME" : "2017-03-23 06:33:06",
        "SEND_TIME" : "2017-03-23 11:45:26 am",
        "STATUS" : "ON",
        "TO" : "2",
        "TYPE" : "VISITORS"
    }
}

var keys = Object.keys(notifications);
if (notifications.hasOwnProperty(keys[0]) {
    if (notifications[keys[0]].STATUS == 'ON') {
        notifications[keys[0]].STATUS = 'OFF';
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur relpy. if status value does not updated and does not repeat loop.how can i do this

Comment: For looping over all the notifications:
    var keys = Object.keys(notifications);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (notifications.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])) {
            // Do something
        }
    }